# calculate $\left|C_{S_{12}}(\sigma)\right|$ whereas $\sigma=\left(1...6\right)\left(7...12\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, permutation-cycles

### Question

calculate  $\left|C_{S_{12}}(\sigma)\right|$ whereas $\sigma=\left(1...6\right)\left(7...12\right)$

### My try

we want to calc the size of the set $\{t\sigma=\sigma t\}$

consider instead $\sigma\mapsto t\sigma t^{-1}$

We know that any permutation that two permutation are replaceable
(idk the exact term that means that $a=bab^{-1}$) iff they have the
same cycle structure.

therefore we need to find the amount of permutation in $\sigma_{12}$with
2 6-order cycles. this is $\left(\begin{array}{c}
12\\
6
\end{array}\right)$ .

Now according to orbit- stabilizer that means that

$|S_{12}|=G_{\sigma}$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
12\\
6
\end{array}\right)$

so $\frac{12!}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
12\\
6
\end{array}\right)}=G_{\sigma}$

And this is the size I look for?

Comment: The conjugacy class of $\sigma$ (= the correct term for the elements of the form $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}$ for some $\alpha\in S_{12}$) is bigger than that. For example the two permutations of the type $(6,6)$, $\sigma$ and $(123465)(789\ldots12)$ both correspond to the same partition of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,12\}$ into two disjoint subsets of size $6$. But, you are also overcounting those partitions because the selections of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ give rise to the same partition.

Comment: hmmm conjugacy doesn't mean that $\exists g\in G$ such $a=g^{-1}bg$?

Comment: Why don't you first try your hand with $\sigma_4=(12)(34)$ in $S_4$ as well as $\sigma_6=(123)(456)\in S_6$. In those small cases you can verify the answer more or less by brute force, and you see what factors you need to take into account. For verification, the class of $\sigma_4$ has three elements, and the class of $\sigma_6$ has $40$ elements, implying that the respective centralizers have size $8$ (resp. $18$).

Comment: Yes, it does. But you called it something else *replaceable*?? Never heard of!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yeah, how do you say that two elements are related like this $a=bab^{-1}$

Comment: They are called *conjugates*.

Comment: how do you call for this $a=g^{-1}bg$ for general g in G?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't really understand why you want to involve conjugacy classes rather than just compute the centralizer directly. The centralizer of an $n$-cycle in $S_n$ has order $n$ (all powers of the cycle), and the centralizer of this element must either fix both $6$-cycles or interchange them, so it has order $2\cdot 6^2 = 72$.

Comment: @DerekHolt cam you explain the last line please?

Comment: True, @DerekHolt. It just seemed to me that the asker wanted to follow the route of counting the size of the conjugacy class, but was caught speeding.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you please write a detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can calculate the centralizer of this and any
other permutation. Let $\sigma=(1,2,\ldots,6)(7,8,\ldots,12)$.
Let
$$
\tau=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \ldots &  12\\
i_1 & i_2 & \ldots &  i_{12}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we have (of permutations we multiply from right to left)
$$
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \ldots &  12\\
i_1 & i_2 & \ldots  & i_{12}
\end{pmatrix}
(1,2,3,4,5,6)(7,8,9,10,11,12)
\begin{pmatrix}
i_1 & i_2 & \ldots & i_{12}\\
1 & 2 & \ldots &  12
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
=(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{6})(i_7, i_8, \ldots, i_{12}).
$$
Now $\tau\in C(\sigma)$ if and only if $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma$.
Hence we have the equality
$$
(1,2,\ldots,6)(7,8,\ldots,12)=(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{6})(i_7, i_8, \ldots, i_{12}).
$$
If $i_1$ and $i_7$ are given, the remaining symbols $i_k$ are
uniquely defined. There are exactly $12$ possibilities for $i_1$.
After $i_1$ is chosen for $i_7$ there are exactly 6 possibilities.

So $|C(\sigma)|=12\cdot6$.

Comment: Thank you, why are there 12? and then 6?

Comment: I think you mean $i_1$ and $i_7$ at the end rather than $i_1$ and $i_2$.

Comment: Yes, of course $i_7$ not $i_2$ thank you. Corrected.